# how to transfer image (HBITMAP) of application to another application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i tryed to transfer image data using device contexts and handle to bitmaps but the handles is invalid in another application. I need to transfer image data or DC data from one application to another. How this can be accomplished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to send images across processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536331/most-efficient-way-to-send-images-across-processes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate here of why they're invalid:
[Sharing HDC between different processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499487/sharing-hdc-between-different-processes)

And here's a response on techniques to share image data:
[Most efficient way to send images across processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536331/most-efficient-way-to-send-images-across-processes)

Comment: Asked and answered, no short-cuts.

Comment: @Sergey: you're right.  There's no answer except the documented, reliable solution.