# Image transmission between processes too slow in python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, ipc, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to send images (4000, 3000, 3) between two processes.
My first process acquires the image with a camera, attaches to it some metadata, another image and then sends the whole thing to the second process, which processes it.

I want to have a maximal delay of 0.2 seconds between the moment the image is acquired and the moment the processing is over.

Let's assume the way I acquire and process the image is optimal.

I tried 2 methods to send the image, with a queue (`mp.Queue`) and with a shared array (`mp.Array('i', 4000*3000*3)`)
Both took to much time. 
The `Queue.put()` method takes about 0.5 seconds to send the package.
Copying the image in a shared array like this:

`shared_array[:] = img.copy()`

Takes about 2 seconds.

So my question is, is anyone aware of a faster way to transit two images between two processes?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to send images across processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536331/most-efficient-way-to-send-images-across-processes)

Comment: @APhillips thanks for your answer, I understood the first part, but none of what he said in the image transfer via shared memory part.
I'll investigate and get back to you.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, but  found this topic which did:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share Large, Read-Only Numpy Array Between Multiprocessing Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found this question, which has been answered, and addressed my problem using `sharedmem` module