# Grabbing a Window's Pixel Data

Tags: image, bitmap, window, copy

In Windows, I am trying to figure out how to grab pixel data from a window. Say you have Microsoft Word open and you want to grab a screenshot of only that app. How is that done?

Is this a good process?

1. Figure out where the application is on screen (How would I do that?)
2. Copy the screen's pixel buffer data to a bitmap (how do I grab screen data?)

Thanks

Comment: You have to use the folling api's [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) [GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx) [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx) [SetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This question gets asked a lot. I'm surprised you couldn't find the existing copies, like [Screenshot of window](http://stackoverflow.com/q1803498/) and [Capture window pixels regardless of its z-order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8707023/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Windows SDK documentation. The example worked well for me.